# Binomial coefficient formula reduction

Tags: statistics, binomial-coefficients

I think I need to use $(x+y)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} x^{n-k} y^k$, but I can't figure out how. I am trying to see why

$$\frac{y!}{x!(y-x)!} \lambda^x \mu^{y-x} / \sum_{x,r:x+r=y}\frac{y!}{x! r!} \lambda^x \mu^r$$

is the same as

$${y \choose x} \left(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda + \mu} \right)^x \left( \frac{\mu}{\lambda + \mu} \right)^{y-x}$$

But can't see why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numerator of your LHS is by definition of ${n \choose k}$ equal to $${y \choose x} \lambda^x \mu^{y-x}$$ 
The denominator can be rewritten as:
$$\sum_{r=0}^y {y \choose r} \mu^r \lambda^{y-r} = (\mu+\lambda)^y = (\mu+\lambda)^x (\mu+\lambda)^{y-x}$$

Now if you take a ratio of the simplified numerator and denominator, you will get the desired answer,

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the index r starts at $r=0$ and the maximum value of r is if $x=0$. That means $r=y-x=y-0=y$.

$$\sum_{r=0}^y\frac{y!}{x! r!} \lambda^x \mu^r \overset{substitution}{=}\sum_{r=0}^y\frac{y!}{(y-r)! r!}\lambda^{y-r} \mu^r$$

Now apply the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 0):

If you match the two expressions and cancel terms, you find that you need to show
$$(\lambda + \mu)^y = \sum_{x,r : x+r = y} \frac{y!}{x! r!} \lambda^x \mu^r.$$

Comment: how so, if in the second expression, the two denominators are: $(\lambda + \mu)^x$ and $(\lambda + \mu)^{y-x}$

Comment: which would mean that $(\lambda + \mu)^x(\lambda + \mu)^{y-x} = \sum_{x,r:x+r=y} \frac{y!}{x!r!}\lambda^x \mu^r$

Comment: which is $(\lambda + \mu)^y$...

Comment: can't show it..

Comment: it is intuitive that that is the result because we are finding all the combinations that sum up to $y$. The crux must be in re-writing the $x,r:x+r=y$ intelligently